Set a view (v1) to meet RLS but allow access to it from other functions or views even if their invoker can't invoke (v1) directly
imagine i have a view (V1) How can I restrict anonymous access to that specific view while allowing other roles and the database itself to access the view? Also, (other public views that make use of (V1)) (that anonymous users can access) should still be accessible as long as the specific view (referred to as v1) is not accessed (alone) or (directly).
i tried to set securtiy_invoker on my v1 which meant that even the views or functions that use v1 would now also refuse if the invoker doesn't have access to v1. But what i wanted was different and hence came my question.
